# If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are exchangeable, does it guarantee that $E(X_1)=E(X_2)$?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are exchangeable, does it guarantee that $E(X_1)=E(X_2)$?
If yes, why does this relation hold?

Thank you,

Comment: This is a direct consequence of the definition of [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables). Is there a part of the definition you are unclear about?

Comment: I know that the exchangeability of $X_1$ and $X_2$ implies that their joint distribution remains unchanged when the two r.v.s are flipped, but I am not sure why that implies the relation I described.

Comment: How does my definition of exchangeability imply that the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are in in fact identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X_1, X_2)$ and $(X_2, X_1)$ have the same joint distribution, then their marginal distributions must also be the same. In particular, the first component has the same distribution, i.e. $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution. Consequently, their expectations must also be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Being exchangeable guarantees the (much weaker) condition that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same (marginal) cumulative distribution functions, which in turns guarantees that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same expectations.